# How to link aws-sdk-cpp with CMake?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, cmake

I have found that Amazon has a SDK in C++ ([github link](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-cpp)), but I cannot get to link it via CMake...

I have done the steps in the readme:

```
mkdir BUILD_DIR
cd BUILD_DIR
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
make
sudo make install
```

but what is the way to link it via CMake?

I have tried `find_package(aws-cpp-sdk)`, but it does not find it. Any help please? :)

---

Ok, in the end I have found a way to do it:

```
set(AWS_CPP_SDK_INCLUDE_DIRS /path/to/include/aws CACHE STRING "aws-cpp-sdk include directories")
set(AWS_CPP_SDK_CORE_LIB "-l:/path/to/libaws-cpp-sdk-core.so" CACHE STRING "aws-cpp-sdk link core lib")
set(AWS_CPP_SDK_S3_LIB "-l:/path/to/libaws-cpp-sdk-s3.so" CACHE STRING "aws-cpp-sdk link S3 lib")
```

And then use the variables for linking

Thanks @Tsyvarev for the help, it gave me this idea

But the problem is that it say that it don't find the aws-cpp-sdk-core.so at execution time:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libaws-cpp-sdk-core.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: As usual, use [find_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_file.html) for detect include directory, use [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html) for find needed libraries.

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/build-cmake.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in the end I have found a way to do it:

```
set(AWS_CPP_SDK_INCLUDE_DIRS /path/to/include/aws CACHE STRING "aws-cpp-sdk include directories")
set(AWS_CPP_SDK_CORE_LIB "-l:/path/to/libaws-cpp-sdk-core.so" CACHE STRING "aws-cpp-sdk link core lib")
set(AWS_CPP_SDK_S3_LIB "-l:/path/to/libaws-cpp-sdk-s3.so" CACHE STRING "aws-cpp-sdk link S3 lib")
```

And then use the variables for linking

Thanks @Tsyvarev for the help, it gave me this idea

---

And finally, the libs should be moved/copied to /usr/local/lib instead of /usr/local/lib/linux/intel64/Release/

Solved :)